# Object array to generic array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

See the code

```
Integer[] array = (Integer[]) new Object[size];
```

this obviously do not works, I understand perfectly.

but why with generics works?

```
T[] array = (T[]) new Object[size];
```

if T is Integer class, after that line the array will be Object[] type, but why cast is possible? does not throw ClassCastException?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: As a rule of thumb, generics and arrays don't mix well.

Comment: Avoid generics and arrays. Avoid casting arrays. This is a an area of the language that is somewhat unsafe - it's very easy to end up with an `ArrayStoreException` at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but why with generics works?

It's because the generic version is type-erased and compiled to following -

```
Object[] array = new Object[size];
```

Comment: SomeClass<T extends Comparable<T>> {
 T[] array;
}

will be translated to 

Comparable<Object>[] array;

right?

Comment: Just compiled it on my eclipse and it's `java.lang.Comparable[] array;`.

Comment: You can get the idea behind it here - [What is a reifiable type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ106).

Answer (score 2):

Type casts are done at runtime that's why you get a cast exception. Generics on the other hand are compile time features of Java. When you declare

```
class Foo<T> {
    T bar;
}
```

the field bar is actually of type Object (or if you use bounds like ? extends ... of whatever base class you chose). When you use the class for example like this

```
Foo<Foobar> foo = new Foo<>();
foo.bar = new Foobar();
Foobar foobar = foo.bar;
```

the compiler will translate the last assignment to something equivalent to

```
Foobar foobar = (Foobar) foo.bar;
```

because it knows that the return value, even though internally of type Object will always a Foobar.